# Access array items in post request object in Node

Tags: json, node.js, express, post

I am sending an object similar to myJsonObj below as a post request in node.
On the server side I want to loop through the object and build new objects looking like this `{ "id": 50, "damage_type": "light" }` these will be used to call my SQL string builder.

My issue at the moment is that I dont know how to get to my damage_type items. I get the id fine `console.log(req.body.id)` . But `console.log(req.body.damage_type[0]);` Does not print anything.
If i do a console.log(req.body) this is what I see in the terminal

```
{ id: '50',
      'damage_type[]': [ 'missing', 'broken', 'light' ] }
```

So I am a bit confused to why I cannot access the array items in the object.

```
let myJsonObj = {
        "id": 50,
        "damage_type": ["missing", "broken", "light"]
      }


router.post('/damage', (req, res) => 

// structure I want to send to createSql function.
// { "poi_id": 50, "damage_type": "light" }
{


    req.body.damage_type.forEach(function(damage) {
    let objToDb = {}
    objToDb.id = req.body.id;
    objToDb.damage_type = damage
    createSql(objtoDb)
    })

    queries.createSql(objtoDb).then(damage => {
        //do things
    };
};
```

Hopefully someone can help a beginner =)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `damage_type` is actually `damage_type[]` you will need to check way you are sending `damage_type` and remove the extra `[]`

Comment: Thanks, I though that might been the case. I must have created my object wrong then. But it passed json validator. Will need to play around

Comment: Nope, dont get it. I can get to my damages like Obj.damage_type[0] like I would expect in the chrome console after hardcoding the object on the client side. But If I have sent it as req object to my route I cannot.